# Iterating 2 lists to form a dictionary with unique key but multiple items

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got 2 lists, one with plate numbers that has duplicates in it, and the other with corresponding groups that each plate belongs to. Duplicated number means that the plate belongs to several groups. I'm trying to make a dict with the following output:

```
L1 = ['173', '607', '607', '581', '522', '522']
L2 = ['fleet 6', 'fleet 4', 'fleet 6', 'Toyota', 'Maintenance', 'fleet 1']

# Desirable output
# '173': 'fleet 6'
# '607': ['fleet4', 'fleet6']
# '581': 'Toyota'
# '522': ['Maintenance', 'fleet 1']
```

I have no clue how to cluster values as lists from L2 to match with duplicates from L1, along with singles, any ideas please?

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach to see if that help.  It's only one way to solve it, prob. easy to understand.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

L1 = ['173', '607', '607', '581', '522', '522']

L2 = ['fleet 6', 'fleet 4', 'fleet 6', 'Toyota', 'Maintenance', 'fleet 1']

# Desirable output
# '173': 'fleet 6'
# '607': ['fleet4', 'fleet6']
# '581': 'Toyota'
# '522': ['Maintenance', 'fleet 1']

dc = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(len(L1)):
    item = L1[i]
    dc[item].append(L2[i])

pprint(dc)
```

#### Edit:

As @KellyBundy suggests, you could use this more `pythonic` way to solve it too:

```
dc = defaultdict(list)

for item, plate in zip(L1, L2):
    dc[item].append(plate)

pprint(dc)
```

Comment: I'll try to ride both snippets in general architecture of my program and see whichever shoots the best! Thank you so much for your input

Comment: *"Using standard library should be considered/encouraged (first)"* - Then why do you suggest index-looping instead of `zip`?

Comment: I think your wording of that advice is fine, you'd just better *follow* your own advice :-) That indexed looping is really unpythonic

Comment: Daniel, your method has eventually worked out! Ftagliacarne's snippet worked with only limited amount of plates, but when the amount of them grew over a thousand I've started experiencing 'Remote server disconnect" problem, while populating list dynamically, which never happened while using defaultdict lib

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
d = {}

L1 = ['173', '607', '607', '581', '522', '522']
L2 = ['fleet 6', 'fleet 4', 'fleet 6', 'Toyota', 'Maintenance', 'fleet 1']

for l1, l2 in zip(L1, L2):
   d[l1] = d.get(l1, [])
   d[l1].append(l2)
```

Where the `d.get()` function gets the item and if the key does not exist returns an empty list

Comment: This one is even closer, and seems to spare me using libraries. Thanx a lot!

Comment: Awesome! I think always having a list even with one item is more useful, but that's up to you.

Comment: Unfortunately I ain't got any choice

Answer (score 0):

You can make this:

```py
result = {key: [] for key in L1}

for i, value in enumerate(L2):
    result[L1[i]].append(value)
```

Simple and quick!

**Steps**

1. Create and dict with all keys of L1 and an empty list in value
2. Add the value of L2 (know the key by the index on enumerate)

Comment: `result = dict.fromkeys(L1, [])` could be another possibility

Comment: @cards Nah, really not.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy mmm, is the default value shared among each key?

Comment: @cards I wouldn't call it default, and [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) doesn't, either (unlike for get/pop/setdefault), but yes, that same object becomes the value for all those keys. The doc also warns about that and suggests a dict comp instead.

Comment: @cards As said @Kelly Bundy, this doesn't work because `dict.fromkeys(L1, [])`append all keys the **same** list. (The same *pointer*) So when I append something to 1 value, every list has it too.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping):

```
d = {}

for k, v in zip(L1, L2):
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

print(d)
#{'173': ['fleet 6'], '607': ['fleet 4', 'fleet 6'], '581': ['Toyota'], '522': ['Maintenance', 'fleet 1']}
```